# Poptorootviewcontroller with delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, delay, poptoviewcontroller

I have a method "test" that execute poptorootviewcontroller. I want to put some delay before the animation of poptorootviewcontroller. Here is my code :

```
-(void)test{
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                      delay: 2.5
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                 }
                 completion:nil];
}
```

But it doesn't work.
Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted is for performing an animation, not delaying.

A good solution would be to use `dispatch_after`:

```
-(void)test{
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    });
```

Replace the `2.5` with whatever delay you want.

Comment: Awesome!! And how can I add animations after the delay?

Comment: If you want to animate the "pop", pass `YES` instead of `NO` to `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`.

Comment: And for the other types of animations? (curve,flip...)

Comment: What other animations? What animations are you trying to do after you dismiss the view controller?

Comment: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking about in regards to this question.