# UITabBarController child view controller reset -Swift2 iOS

Tags: ios, swift2, uitabbarcontroller, selectedindex, childviewcontroller

I have a tabBarController with 2 tabs: tabZero and tabOne.

tabZero contains a navController and 2 child view controllers. viewControllerRed is the nav's root which has a button that pushes on viewControllerBlue.

viewControllerBlue has a button: `buttonPressed`. When buttonPressed is tapped, the tab index is switched to tabOne via `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex 1`

My problem is after the switch, if I press tabZero viewControllerBlue is still showing. How do I reset to the nav's root vc (viewControllerRed) after using pressing the buttonPressed in viewControllerBlue?

I can't use `popToRootViewController` because there are 2 transitions happening at once. The first is I'm changing the tabBar index and the other is I the root vc reset. I need the reset to happen in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the pop function in a delay without animation.

```
[self.navigationController performSelector:@selector(popToRootViewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
```

or

[Poptorootviewcontroller with delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26978577/poptorootviewcontroller-with-delay)

Comment: thanks I'm trying in a few. I'll let you know results

Comment: Thanks. I used self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)